# Не будет ли проблем при статической компиляции С++ библиотеки?

Tags: c++, dll

Сейчас я компилю библиотеку с ключом "Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)" - но у некоторых пользователей выдает ошибку.
Важно учесть, что программа, вернее плагин работает в среде 3ds Max.

Начал поставлять со своей библиотекой файлы msvcp110.dll и msvcr110.dll.
Просто ложу их в одну папку с моей библиотекой, но при этом возникла другая проблема - у некоторых пользователей стали медленно выполняться некоторые функции в 3ds max.
Насколько я понимаю, при вызове моей библиотеки подгружаются библиотеки msvc*110.dll и в дальнейшем они же используются 3ds max.

Возможное решение - компиляция с ключом "Multi-threaded (/MT)" - то есть эти библиотеки (msvc*110.dll и прочие ) будут встраиваться в мою dll.
Поможет ли это в моем случае, и будет ли 3ds max в этом случае подгружать "правильные" библиотеки, игнорируя встроенные в мою библиотеку ?
Нужно ли выставлять опцию "Use of MFC" в "Use MFC in a Static Library" 
Спасибо!

Comment: "Use of MFC" если вы его не используете - скорее всего не нужно трогать.
"Multi-threaded (/MT)" включает в ваш исполняемый файл код, который бы иначе выполнялся из  msvc*.dll. При такой линковке эти dll будут отсутствовать в импортах полученного файла, следовательно не будут загружаться вашей программой. 3DS сможет их загрузить сама.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов стоит запостить как ответ :)

Comment: ОК :-) На самом деле, все сложнее: вставляется разный код в зависимости от настроек линковки...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Use of MFC" если вы его не используете - скорее всего не нужно трогать. "Multi-threaded (/MT)" включает в ваш исполняемый файл код, который бы иначе выполнялся из msvc*.dll. При такой линковке эти dll будут отсутствовать в импортах полученного файла, следовательно не будут загружаться вашей программой. 3DS сможет их загрузить сама.